# R: `scan` undocumented behavior?

Tags: r

To demonstrate the behavior under consideration:

```
sst = scan(text='44 45 46 47 48 49 50\n51 52 53 54 55 56 57',
           what=list(age='numeric',
                     weight='numeric', 
                     oxygen='numeric', 
                     runTime='numeric', 
                     restPulse='numeric', 
                     runPulse='numeric', 
                     maxPulse='numeric'))
```

I expect this (based on the documentation) to give me a list of seven numeric columns. What it returns in fact is:

```
R> str(sst)
List of 7
 $ age      : chr [1:2] "44" "51"
 $ weight   : chr [1:2] "45" "52"
 $ oxygen   : chr [1:2] "46" "53"
 $ runTime  : chr [1:2] "47" "54"
 $ restPulse: chr [1:2] "48" "55"
 $ runPulse : chr [1:2] "49" "56"
 $ maxPulse : chr [1:2] "50" "57"
```

This produces the correct answer.

```
sst = scan(text='44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57',
           what=list(age=double(),
                     weight=double(), 
                     oxygen=double(), 
                     runTime=double(), 
                     restPulse=double(), 
                     runPulse=double(), 
                     maxPulse=double()))
```

But why does the first statement fail? Is there some subtlety to `scan` that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument `what` should be provided by an object of the desired type not by the type name.

See `?scan`:

> what
>
> the type of what gives the type of data to be read.

And the example:

```
scan("ex.data", what = list("","","")
```

Each `""` standing for an empty string, indicating the desired type is a character string.

In your case, you can do for example something like this:

```
sst = scan(text='44 45 46 47 48 49 50\n51 52 53 54 55 56 57',
       what=list(age=0,
                 weight=0, 
                 oxygen=0, 
                 runTime=0, 
                 restPulse=0, 
                 runPulse=0, 
                 maxPulse=0))

str(sst)
List of 7
 $ age      : num [1:2] 44 51
 $ weight   : num [1:2] 45 52
 $ oxygen   : num [1:2] 46 53
 $ runTime  : num [1:2] 47 54
 $ restPulse: num [1:2] 48 55
 $ runPulse : num [1:2] 49 56
 $ maxPulse : num [1:2] 50 57
```

Or the solution you tried works as well.